# UITableViewCell Has Incorrect Shadow Size

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I originally had an issue where the UITableViewCells would have multiple shadows because I was making a call to add a shadow to the contentView in `dequeueReusableCell`. After learning that this reused cells, I figured the proper way to initialize the shadows on the tableViewCells was in the initialization function.

In my custom table view cell class I call:

```
override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    contentView.addShadow()
}
```

Now the shadows are the incorrect size and I need help figuring out the proper way to set the shadow size to match the content.

Here is my shadow function, which is added as a UIView extension:

```
func addShadow() {
        self.layer.masksToBounds = false
        self.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.23
        self.layer.shadowRadius = 2.0
        self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 1.0, height: 1.0)
        self.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, byRoundingCorners: .allCorners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 8, height: 8)).cgPath
}
```

Here is a screenshot showing the initial shadows and then the images that are loaded in their place: [image]

The images are put onto the tableview cells with this function, which is called in the `dequeueReusableCell` function:

```
func makeBackgroundImageCall(anime: Anime) {
        guard let url = anime.getCoverImageOriginalUrl() else { return }
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
            if (error != nil) {
                print(error as Any)
                return
            }
            guard let image = UIImage(data: data!) else { return }
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async() { [weak self] in
                guard let contentView = self?.contentView else { return }
                let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
                contentView.addSubview(imageView)
                imageView.pin(to: contentView) // sets constraints to fill parent
            }
        }.resume()
    }
```

Lastly, here is my `dequeueReusableCell` function:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell =  tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellReuseID) as! AnimeTableCell
        if let anime = trendingAnimes[indexPath.section] {
            cell.makeBackgroundImageCall(anime: anime)
        }
        return cell
    }
```

Another note is that this is all programatic, there's no storyboard so this is why I'm using `init` instead of `awakeFromNib`.
How can I get the shadow to properly overlay the uiTableViewCell and its content image?

Answer (score 0):

```
mylayer.frame = self.bounds;
```

try to set bound for the shadow layer.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the shadowPath when your cell is first initialized, and doesn't have its final size yet.
From your example it looks like your cells are rectangular. In this case you don't need to set a shadowPath at all, and the shadow will fit the shape and size of the cell.
If you do want to define a custom shadowPath, you will need to create it after the cell is resized to fit its contents.